# Contar pagos del mes por dia en MySql

Tags: mysql, distinct, count

Hola estoy tratando de hacer un query que me devuelva el contar cuantos pagos se hicieron en al dia de un mes, hasta ahora obtuve los pagos con **DISTINCT** y

```
SELECT distinct DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%d/%m/%Y') created_at  FROM pagos_ where Month(created_at) = Month(CURDATE());
```

pero necesito contarlos, con un **COUNT()**, pero contar el de cada dia y que la tabla me los separe por dias. Alguien sabe como puedo hacer esto?

mi tabla de pagos_ tiene la siguiente estructura

```
Columns:
id int(50) AI PK 
created_at timestamp 
id_alumno int(12) 
id_cliente int(12) 
concepto varchar(50) 
amount decimal(10,2) 
prorroga varchar(45) 
saldo_pendiente varchar(45) 
saldo_afavor varchar(45) 
tipo_pago varchar(45) 
referencia varchar(45)
```

Lo que busco es algo que me devuelva:

```
// 01-05-2020 / 4-05-2020 / 6-05-2020
// 2          / 7         / 11
// etc ,,,
```

Comment: La estructura de tu tabla y algunos datos de prueba ayudaría mucho a tu pregunta

Comment: ya agregue la estructura de mi tabla, solo quiero que me diga 7 del 01-01-2020 . 12 del 05-01-2020 , etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estabas cerca, haces un count y después de obtener los del mes actual, simplemente haces un "group by" de cada día.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%d/%m/%Y') as "dia", 
       count(created_at) as "nº pagos" 
       FROM users 
       where Month(created_at) = Month(CURDATE()) 
       group by Day(created_at);
```

Comment: el buen **group by** , como pude pasarlo por alto